# MiKTeX portable fontconfig file location configuration

Tags: fontspec, miktex

I moved MiKTeX portable to another directory, and after that there are issues with loading fontconfig. Specifically, when compiling with `xelatex`, fontconfig cannot be loaded. Its location is apparently pointing to the original location `OLDLOCATION`.

Where does MiKTeX keep such information?

```
(CURRENTLOCATION\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
(CURRENTLOCATION\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty (CURRENTLOCATION\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def)
(CURRENTLOCATION\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd)Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file "
OLDLOCATION/fontconfig/config/localfonts.conf"
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the portable version. But in my miktex the fonts.conf in `<Root UserConfig>/fontconfig/config` contains explicit pathes. You should also check localfonts.conf and localfonts2.conf.